# Automatically logon to Windows RDP session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, login

I've been trying to find an answer for this for more than a year now, so I guess it's either impossible or there are way too many questions using the same keywords.

What I'm trying to achieve is this: I have a network of about 100 computers. From time to time, I need to do something remotely, and I use Remote Desktop. **Please note that there are no servers available, nor is any 3rd party software an acceptable solution**. I have an administrator account on each of those computers, but the problem is that many of them are set up so that a generic standard user logs in automatically (users simply don't need to have passwords, and mostly refuse to have them, and my employer is fine with this). Whenever I try RD on any of these computers, it says there's another user already logged in, and I must click "Yes" and wait until the system logs me in. **That's a lot of time lost on switching windows and clicking**.

I have no problem with actual people denying my logon attempts, but when there's a lot of work, i WoL these computers in the evening and then do what needs to be done. But, as the auto-login feature is on, I must click a button and wait for each of 100 sessions.

Is there a way, perhaps using an mstsc.exe parameter or something, to somehow try to login automatically? In either case, whether someone's actually using the computer or not, I always try and click the button - if I get rejected, that means somebody's using the computer, and that's fine. I come back later.

Thanks in advance for any help with this one.

Comment: If the main problem is the locally logged-on user on each machine why not use a script or tool to remotely log out the user? More effectively would be to change your maintenance to scripts that are executed remotely without UI.

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for the tip! I agree it would be absolutely best to create tasks and execute them remotely, however for some reason I can't get past the infamous admin$ share. I tried the "net use" command, and it works, however after I try to run a task using schtasks.exe, it says access denied ... something something ... because of admin$. Now I have found tons of advices regarding said share, but unfortunately nothing helped. Of course, scripts all works perfectly on the domain part of the network.

Answer (score 0):

Robert's suggestion to force logout the automatically logged in user when you WoL a computer would seem to be the best option, as when you don't WoL the PC you do want to offer the logged in user the 100 seconds to decline or accept.

You could look into setting up WinRM/WinRS and using Powershell to send your forced logout command.

Off the top of my head the remote logout command would be something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'REMOTECOMPUTER' -ScriptBlock { logoff 2 }
```

or maybe it's `logoff 1` ... the number is the sessionID ... you could also maybe test using the `shutdown -l` command which doesn't shutdown but instead logs off the current user

Comment: Thanks, I will try this first thing in the morning! Wanted to give you an upvote, however my rep still won't allow me to do so.

Comment: just mark it as answered if it ends up working for you.. cheers!